# FullCalendar: How to re-add events that were part of original events array?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Why can't a removed event be re-added to FullCalendar if it was part of the original events array?

This works (http://jsfiddle.net/fTu98/1/):

```
// A simple event object
e = {id: 1, title: 'a', start: Date.now()/1000 };

// Create calendar with no events
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({ events: [] });

// Add event to calendar
$("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent', e);

// Remove event from the calendar
$("#calendar").fullCalendar('removeEvents', 1);

// Re-add event
$("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent', e);
```

While this doesn't (http://jsfiddle.net/BNmrQ/2/):

```
// A simple event object
e = {id: 1, title: 'a', start: Date.now()/1000 };

// Create calendar with the event
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({ events: [e] });

// Remove event from the calendar
$("#calendar").fullCalendar('removeEvents', 1);

// Try re-adding event, doesn't work!
$("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent', e);
```

I guess the [documentation for `renderEvent`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/) hints at this by saying that it "Renders a *new* event on the calendar," but I don't understand why that's the case.

Thanks!

Comment: I add this to the bug tracker: https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=1997

Comment: @arshaw Thanks for that and for creating/maintaining fullcalendar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this bug has been resolved in version 2.0.0 of FullCalendar:
https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=1997

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer to "Why" but I can show you a work around

if you copy the event object into another object it will work (using the new object)

```
e2 = $.extend({}, e);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BNmrQ/5/